# Python: Communication Errors between multiple threaded classes

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, class, sockets

So, I've always had this problem, and no matter what, can't seem to solve it.

When using multithreading, I can-simply-not get the classes to talk to each other.

Yes, I have some pretty ugly code to back my claims.

In this case, I will be using code from a small proxy as an example.

This class handles data from the server to the client that is intercepted;

```
class HandleInbound(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global ftwn
        self.dsi.connect(('208.95.184.130',7255))
        self.dsi.setblocking(0)
        while True:
            try:
                f = open('odat.tmp','r+')
                a = f.read()
                if len(a) != 0:
                    self.dsi.send(open('odat.tmp').read())
                    open('odat.tmp','w').write("")
                dat = self.dsi.recv(65356)
                open('idat.tmp','w').write(dat)
                udat = dat.encode("hex")
                Log(udat, 0, ftwn)

            except socket.timeout:
                print("DSI Timedout")
            except socket.error as e:
                Log(e, 2, ftwn)
            except Exception as e:
                raise
                print("In;",e)
                self.dsi.close()
                sys.exit()
```

This is my problemitc class. Keep that in mind.

This one works as intended, handling traffic from the client to the server;

```
class HandleOutbound(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global conn, addr, ftwn
        print("Client connected from {}.".format(addr))
        conn.setblocking(0)
        while True:
            try:
                f = open('idat.tmp','r+')
                a = f.read()
                if len(a) != 0:
                    conn.send(open('idat.tmp').read())
                    open('idat.tmp','w').write("")
                dat = conn.recv(65356)
                open('odat.tmp','w').write(dat)
                udat = dat.encode("hex")
                Log(udat, 0, ftwn)

            except socket.timeout:
                print("Conn Timedout")
            except socket.error as e:
                Log(e, 2, ftwn)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Out;",e)
                conn.close()
                sys.exit()
```

As you can see, the current form of communications is through temporary files.

HandleOutbound, or for lack of time and space, Class 2, reads a file. If there is no data in the file, it attempts to get some and put it there for the HandleInbound, or, Class 1 to read.

Class 2 does it's job, and Class 1 gets lazy at the sending the data part of the bargain, and later fails to even notice the file and code are there, however, it does have time to write 2GB log files of "Non-blocking errors" to my computer in the 5 minutes it takes me to figure out what and why.

I have previously, and always try first, with varying levels of success, global variables. Today it was having none of that.

I also attempted to communicate straight from Class 1 to Class 2, or even using Booleans, but my luck skill ran out.

I have rewritten Class 1 multiple times over. First to see if something was hidden. No change. Then to match identically, or as close to as possible, to Class 2. I eventually also C/P'd the thing and renamed the variables.

At least I am having consistent results - No changes!

There also seems to be little or no beginner or intermediate guides or documents that corner and tackle this issue, as I have been looking for a while, as in years-keeping in mind I can't "Just google it".

The logs, and console leave no help other than "Non-blocking socket operation was unable to complete instantly".

I know the code is bad, the style is sloppy, and fragmented, but it should, in theory, work regardless, or throw a fit of varying levels constantly, correct?

Comment: As an exercise, why not try to describe - step by step by step - exactly what you think happens in `HandleInbound` when 'odat.tmp' is empty?

Comment: I completely missed that comment. By months :/ I'm looking back at it now, and it's a massive trainwreck. I'll just restart from scratch, but, thanks for trying!